# Swift: Boolean attributes and KVC mysteries

Tags: swift, core-data, boolean, kvc

So I'm playing with this simple CoreData entity

```
import CoreData

class Figure: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var approx: NSNumber? // Defined as Boolean type without default value
}
```

As you would expect, for a new figure, you get

```
figure.approx # nil
figure.valueForKey("approx") # nil
```

But, if you define the following (yes, I know, I could instead set a default value in the data model, that's not the point)

```
var isApprox: Bool {
  guard let approx = approx else { return false }
  return approx == true
}
```

Then suddenly

```
figure.valueForKey("approx") # false
```

Alright, so for some (to me) mysterious reason, it's actually relying on isApprox. I assumed that it is synthesized and I'm unknowingly overriding it, but if you remove the isApprox declaration and try to call it using KVC, it crashes:

```
figure.valueForKey("isApprox") # Execution was interrupted
```

Going further, if you have the following:

```
class Figure: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var approx: NSNumber?

    var isApproximate: Bool {
      guard let approx = approx else { return false }
      return approx == true
    }
}
```

Now you get

```
figure.valueForKey("approx") # nil - expected
figure.valueForKey("isApproximate") # false - expected
figure.valueForKey("approximate") # false - where does this one come from?
figure.isApprox # error: value of type 'Figure' has no member 'isApprox'
```

I couldn't find any documentation about that, I'm curious to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA) in the Key Value Coding Reference manual covers the behaviour you are noticing.

Specifically, the section entitled "Default Search Pattern for valueForKey:" indicates that for a given key, the valueForKey: will try a range of different accessor methods, including both "key" and "isKey" (and interestingly, it will try "getKey" before either of them).

Comment: Yes, but `<key>` is tried before `<isKey>`, so in this case the `approx` managed property should be used in preference of the `isApprox` property.

Comment: @MartinR Good point.  Perhaps that is because `approx` is an instance var, which are only tried if there are no accessor *methods*.  But I'm guessing.

Comment: `approx` is a Core Data property, and the accessor methods are created dynamically at runtime. But I still wonder why it behaves like this.